# multiprocessing is much slower in __name__ == '__main__' clause

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am learning to use **multiprocessing** module. Why does the following code run much slower than that not in main clause?

Python 3.6.3 [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

```
from multiprocessing import *
from timeit import repeat, timeit

def job(n=1):
    for _ in range(n):
        res = 0
        for i in range(1000000):
            res += i + i**2 + i**3

def multi_core():
    for i in huge_work:
        i.start()
        i.join()

def normal():
    job(times)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    times = 15
    huge_work = [Process(target=job,) for _ in range(times)]
    print("multiprocessing used", timeit(stmt=multi_core, number=1, globals=globals()))
    print("normal used", timeit(stmt=normal, number=1, globals=globals()))
```

It outputted

> multiprocessing used 16.248897644640735
>
> normal used 14.04962034704986

when i removed `if __name__ == '__main__':`, it outputted

> multiprocessing used 1.5223558789665945
>
> normal used 13.696327364173298

what things make the difference so big?

Comment: See [Why does Python's multiprocessing module import \_\_main\_\_ when starting a new process on Windows?](//stackoverflow.com/q/14175348); if you are running Windows not using `if __name__ == '__main__':` will cause issues as the code is run *again*.

Comment: Since this can't be reproduced on Macos or Linux, I'm closing this as a duplicate of that post; you are seeing the result of an error as those processes are exiting early with an error, not a valid result.

Comment: For Python 3, the relevant documentation is found in the [`spawn` and `forkserver` methods section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods) of the programming guidelines. When I add `set_start_method('spawn')` in the `__name__ = "__main__"` section, I can reproduce your times on Macos *and* I get a whole lot of error output for the spawned processes.

Comment: you're using `i.join()` right after `i.start()` that can't be right

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite: they are indeed running the jobs in sequence, but they are doing the same in the `normal` case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters but he showed that without the `if __name__ == '__main__'` it somehow DOES run in parallel which leads me to believe this code is not the one tested...

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite: no, the code does **not** run in parallel. The forked processes each produce an error instead. That's also 'fast'.

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite: note that they don't test if valid output is produced from the jobs! Even a simple check for the process `exitcode` values would already show that the jobs have not run.